# Activity can be used for Navigation Drawer or Should I stick to Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I already have activities on which I want to apply Navigation Drawer. Should I change all my activities into fragments (which is a lot extra work) to use Navigation Drawer or is there a better way so that I can use my activities through it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yup, change them to fragments. It may be a lot of work now, but in the future you won't regret it

Comment: changing to fragments make use of OnCreateView instead of OnCreate and many other modifications are needed to be made. Does this affect the functionality of the activity in any way ?

Comment: No, fortunately Fragments lifecycle is almost the same as the Activity. You should be find by just moving the code onto a Fragment and using onCreateView() callback to get reference to your layout's Views.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Activity for Navigation Drawer instead use Fragments.  A better way to use Navigation Drawer is with fragments. You could use the navigation drawer template provided when creating a create a new Android Application Project which uses fragments.